# Is the Goddess Harp from Skyward Sword the harp Sheik plays in OOT?

Tags: zelda-skyward-sword, zelda-ocarina-of-time

So I just saw someone cosplaying as Sheik on Facebook, and she was carrying Sheik's harp. But the person posting the photo - a mod from a Zelda Facebook page - referred to it as the Goddess Harp specifically.

It would make sense if Sheik's harp *is* the Goddess Harp, because that would imply that it's handed down to Zelda in the same way that, say, it will always be Link who gets the Master Sword. But is there anything canonical to confirm this either way?

Comment: I don't think Sheik's harp (or the Goddess Harp) has ever been mentioned in OoT. If anything, it's the titular Ocarina of Time that's been passed down from royal parent to royal child, which in turn was never mentioned in Skyward Sword.

Comment: Sheik specifically played the Goddess Harp in Hyrule Warriors, maybe they were referencing that as well?

Comment: Yeah, that sounds plausible - want to put it as an answer? Obviously this is backwards-reading from SS into OOT because there's no mention at all of what the harp is in OOT, I just wondered where they got the idea to do that from - beyond the fact that they're both harps played by Zelda.

Comment: @lc9315 - was that directed at me or Nolonar?

Comment: Sorry - that wasn't clear. The "sounds plausible" comment was aimed at your comment on Hyrule Warriors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Yes, it's the same harp.

As [Pyritie's comment](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/223606/is-the-goddess-harp-from-skyward-sword-the-harp-sheik-plays-in-oot#comment302525_223606) points out, [Sheik specifically played the Goddess Harp in *Hyrule Warriors*](http://zelda.wikia.com/wiki/Sheik).

> Sheik with the Goddess's Harp in Hyrule Warriors

[image]

Considering that

1. Sheik played the Goddess Harp in Hyrule Warriors,
2. the two harps look extremely similar, if not identical, and that
3. > Shiek is Zelda in disguise,

it seems that the harp Shiek plays in *Ocarina of Time* is the same harp seen in *Skyward Sword*, the Goddess Harp.

[image]

---

Note: since there is no official/canon info on the subject, a conclusion based on deductive reasoning is our best option.